# Создание нового двумерного массива

Tags: java, массивы

Нужна помощь с решением задачи. Надо заменить исходный массив новым, в котором удалён столбец содержащий только отрицательные значения, если таких столбцов несколько, то удалить только последний столбец, если требуемого столбца нет, то вывести исходный массив.
Я написала код для нахождения первоначального массива, но как задать соответствующие условия не представляю.

```
    public class Lalala {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m = 4, n=5; 
    int  numb;
    boolean in_array = true;
    int[][] arr = new int[m][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            
            do {
                in_array = false;
                
                numb = (int) (Math.random() * 199) -99;
                
                for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                    if ((int) arr[k][j] == (int) numb) {
                        in_array = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } while(in_array);
            arr[i][j] = numb; 
   
            System.out.printf("%5d",numb); 
        }
        System.out.println( ); 
    }
}


}
```

Comment: идти по столбцу и проверять каждое значение на отрицательность. что-то вроде if arr[k][j] < 0

Comment: начинать лучше с последнего столбца, тогда первый встреченный подходящий и окажется последним, который и надо удалить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал @Эникейщик в комментарии, следует проверять каждый столбец, начиная с последнего, что элементы во всех его строках -- отрицательные числа.

Результатом проверки должен стать некий `R`-ый индекс подходящего столбца, если столбец не будет обнаружен, этот индекс окажется равным -1, так как итерации будут происходить от `n - 1`-го столбца до `0`-го по убыванию.  Как только столбец будет обнаружен (обозначим его `R`), можно будет досрочно выйти из внешнего цикла.

При наличии кандидата на удаление, можно либо создать новый массив на `n - 1` столбец, в который следует скопировать нужные данные первоначальной матрицы, пропуская значения в `R`-м столбце. Либо можно, начиная от `R`-го столбца, сдвинуть все строки на 1 элемент влево, и после сдвига уменьшить размер каждой строки на 1 при помощи `Arrays.copyOf`.